# i can't create react app and npm doesn't function correctly

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, create-react-app, npm-install

when i type node -v in my cmd i get the node version normally but when i type npm -v i get this

```
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
10.2.3
```

i tried with all Node versions and i got nothing so i can't create react app when i try the command `npm create-react-app my-react-app` i get this

```
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stdin')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ROG STRIX\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-24T16_46_56_892Z-debug-0.log
```

and everything is good in the path